# PSQL queries creating multiple select queries based on condition to filter out values

Tags: postgresql, go

```
WITH final AS (
    SELECT 'a' AS gname, 'b' AS pname, 'c' AS name, 1 AS gid, 2 AS pid, 3 AS did, 3 AS inp
    UNION
    SELECT 'a1' AS gname, 'b1' AS pname, 'c1' AS name, 11 AS gid, 21 AS pid, 31 AS did, 3 AS inp
)
```

---

[image]

Now I want to write a query depending on the inp column value

```
SELECT 
    (CASE final.inp 
    WHEN 1
        THEN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT(final.gid) AS id, final.gname as name FROM
        final ORDER BY final.gname)
    WHEN 2
        THEN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT(final.pid) AS id, final.pname as name FROM
        final WHERE final.gid = $1 ORDER BY final.pname)
    WHEN 3 
        THEN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT(final.did) AS id, final.name as name FROM
        final WHERE final.pid = $1 ORDER BY final.name)

    END)
        FROM (%s) final;
```

I know this is not a correct way of writing it.

But this will give you an idea what I am trying to do.

if `inp = 1` -> get unique gid's and gname and order by gname

if `inp = 2` -> get unique pid's and pname where gid =  and order by pname.

I want to write this logic in psql.

I know case `When` can have only one column so I have to create two cases for a single `final.inp=1` for name and id.

I ain't able to write this logic because of this part

```
(SELECT DISTINCT(final.pid) AS id, final.pname as name FROM
final WHERE final.gid = $1 ORDER BY final.pname)
```

`WHERE ORDER BY` <--- and passing the same final value to it.
I am not able to implement it. Can anyone help?

Comment: INP can be different in each row of final ?

Comment: Nope will be same

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only assumption

```
select distinct 
case when inp = 1 then gid
       when inp = 2 then pid
       when inp = 3 then did
  end new_id,
  case when inp = 1 then gname
       when inp = 2 then pname
       when inp = 3 then name
  end as name
from final
order by 2
```

[DB Fiddle playground](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f4269398c76dc47774be3d6b29fd6ef0)

Comment: so that means there is not a direct case I have to create separately for order by cases.

Comment: I've updated query, we can use column number

Comment: One more thing I want to use END name <--- not new_name but it will give me an error as column name is getting matched with the alias name how to solve it?

Comment: it can be `end as name`

Comment: nope it's giving me an error :( Did u use AS ? oh :O Thanks a lot :)